# Heavy processing leaves no time for spinner to show

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have this problem where I'm trying to show a spinner (ie: Loading...) right before logic that can take 1 to even 10 seconds depending on how many fields I have to render and also network access.

Here's the current code for the `show` event of the window:

```
this.mainWindow().setLoading({ msg: this.strings.Messages.str_Wait });
this.Utils.formHelper.renderFormFields(this.mainWindow());
this.fieldsRendered = true;
this.hideEmptyTabs(w);
this.mainWindow().setLoading(false);
```

`renderFormFields` is basically a loop that freezes the interface while adding/rendering fields to a form. But it seems to kick in even before the `setLoading` spinner even shows so all the user sees is a blank window with no fields rendered, suddenly being available 2-3 seconds after.

So here's what I did:

```
this.mainWindow().setLoading({ msg: this.strings.Messages.str_Wait });
setTimeout(function () {
    this.Utils.formHelper.renderFormFields(this.mainWindow());
    this.fieldsRendered = true;
    this.hideEmptyTabs(w);
    this.mainWindow().setLoading(false);
}, 1000);
```

So this would basically leave the spinner 1 second to properly show before processing starts. The issue here is that plenty of events are triggered and their logic needs `this` to be the actual scope, not the `window` object, which is `this` in the `setTimeout` function.

I know you can pass the scope as an argument to `setTimeout` but the thing is that all the code that is called uses `this`, literally and needs to, since the same code will be called outside of that `setTimeout` call.

Any ideas so `this` stays the same within `setTimeout`'s function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you declare a variable me and assign this like so:

```
this.mainWindow().setLoading({ msg: this.strings.Messages.str_Wait });
var me = this;
setTimeout(function () {
    me.Utils.formHelper.renderFormFields(me.mainWindow());
    me.fieldsRendered = true;
    me.hideEmptyTabs(w);
    me.mainWindow().setLoading(false);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This works for the block of code itself, but when fields are being rendered, there is plenty of other code that being called that uses   `this` (ie: `this.Utils`) which can't be changed to `me.Utils` since this same code can be called outside of a `setTimeout` call, later on.

Comment: Francis, `this` and `me` are just references. They can be changed everywhere to access the methods you want. So every time you call this methods you have to make sure you are using the proper scope. In this case you showed, it would me `me` like 6ton pointed out.

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes You are right. This actually works, but in my case, due to other factors I did not actually point out in the question. I had to change a few things, but now it works.

Comment: Yes, scope can get a little messy sometimes. Thats why while working with ExtJS, you should always use ExtJS methods. Instead of `setTimeout` you could use `Ext.defer(function(){},1000, me);` then all the scope inside the defer would point out to your controller and you would be able to use the `this` keyword.